# Call of LaTeX via AucTeX 14.0.3 freezes emacs 27.1

Tags: auctex

Since today, I've been experiencing freezes of my emacs/AucTeX config. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with emacs 27.1 (if important, i3 and fizsh as defaults).

The freeze happens when I press `C-c C-c Enter` (to build the current buffer with a TeX file in LaTeX/PS major mode) where I use `Enter` to choose the default command "LaTeX". The pointer moves to the left end of the minibuffer and Emacs freezes entirely, without reacting to `C-g`. After restarting emacs, I was able to reproduce the freeze at the exact event several times.

To rule out configuration errors, I've deinstalled custom packages, removed my .emacs.d directory as well as my .emacs file. I've reinstalled emacs, texlive.

Then, I tried building a minimal .tex file using emacs' plain pdflatex functionality. That worked.

But, then, I reinstalled AucTeX 14.0.3 from elpa (inside emacs), tried again, same freeze.

I'm reading [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80390/19425) about that it could be that emacs 27.1 might be too old for current AucTeX.

**Update:** In the meanwhile, I've manually backported to [AucTeX 13.3](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/auctex-13.3.tar.gz/) (from Jan 17) and the problem has gone. One downside of this is that switching forward to AucTeX 14.0.3 again does not allow me to reproduce the freeze, but instead, I now get the error message described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80499/auctex-buttons-not-working) when performing the same action. Something must have changed using `make install/uninstall` that at least avoids the freeze.

Comment: Can you please do: Uninstall the older AUCTeX via package interface, close all Emacs instances, restart Emacs and install the latest AUCTeX version via package interface.  Close and start Emacs as `emacs -Q`, then in `*scratch*` buffer, eval the following `(progn (setq debug-on-error t) (package-initialize t) (package-activate 'auctex))` (i.e., set the cursor after the last ) and hit C-x C-e) and then open your .tex file and try it again?  Also do `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` to check you don't have any other AUCTeX installation/files sitting on your HD.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're facing two different issues:

##### Updating AUCTeX from 13.x to 14.x:

There were some internal changes in AUCTeX, and supposing that you're using the `package` interface provided by Emacs, you have to:

- Make sure you don't have multiple AUCTeX installations (`M-x list-load-path-shadows RET`)
- Uninstall the 13.x installation (`M-x list-packages RET ...`)
- Close the current Emacs session and restart Emacs
- Install the 14.x version (`M-x list-packages RET ...`)

##### Issues reported [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80389/12242) and probably [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80499/12242)

AUCTeX now requires Emacs 27 and higher.  There was a change in AUCTeX to use the `:local` tag inside `defcustom` instead of `make-variable-buffer-local`.  The implementation in Emacs 27.1 was faulty and was fixed for Emacs 27.2.  This issue is now resolved with AUCTeX 14.0.4 by reverting the usage of `:local` tag, therefore, things should be back to normal state.

Comment: Thanks, @ArashEsbati for these hints. I'm in preparation for updating my aged machine, so, hopefully, the correct(ed) combination will get installed. It's, however, good to know that potentially several issues have been at play in my setting, not just misconfiguration :)